# Как показывать блок по клику?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Собственно вопрос. Как в данном случае поступить? Нужно чтобы по клику на адрес открывалась такая форма: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кликая по крестику, она закрывалась.

Пытался сделать таким образом:

```js
  $(".mapclick").click(function() {
    $(".testblock").Show();
  });
```

Comment: ты там не путаешь классы (".класс") и id('#айди')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```js
$('.open').click(function() {
  $('.form').show('slow');
});

$('.close').click(function() {
  $('.form').hide('slow');
});
```

```css
.form {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: silver;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="open" href="#">open</a>
<div class="form">
  <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
</div>
```